# Finding associated eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Having troubles with this question

Suppose that $\det(A) \not= 0$, and $A$ and $B$ both have eigenvector $v$, but the corresponding eigenvalue is $\lambda_{A}$ for $A$ and $\lambda_{B}$ for $B$. Show that A$^{-1}B$ has the same eigenvector v. Find the eigenvalue associated with this eigenvector for A$^{-1}B$.

Could someone walk me through it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
Bv=\lambda_{B} v\quad\imp\quad
A^{-1}B = \lambda_{B}A^{-1}v;\qquad Av = \lambda_{A}v\quad\imp A^{-1}v = \lambda_{A}^{-1}v
$$
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large A^{-1}Bv} =\lambda_{B}\pars{\lambda_{A}^{-1}v}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large{\lambda_{B} \over \lambda_{A}}\,v} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

From the very definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, you have
$$A\mathbf{v} = \lambda_A\mathbf{v}\tag{1}$$
$$B\mathbf{v} = \lambda_B\mathbf{v}\tag{2}$$
Apply $A^{-1}$ to equation $(1)$ to show that $\mathbf{v}$ is also an eigenvector of $A^{-1}$ but with eigenvalue $\lambda_A^{-1}$. Now substitute equation $(2)$ into $A^{-1}B\mathbf{v}$ and use what we've just learned about $A^{-1}$.